# WinInet / IE11 on Windows 7 TLS 1.2 enabled not working on a website

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, wininet

I have some software where I use Windows WinInet API and IE browser control.

However a Windows 7 user is reporting problems if though TLS options are checked... 
I had the user try open the website using IE11 and that fails as well.
(Which makes sense since it uses the same underlying API as my software)

The site apparently loads correctly in Chome.

Screenshots below showing the error and configuration:

[image]

[image]

Now I looked up the RC4 cipher mention in the IE11 error and found this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3151631/rc4-cipher-is-no-longer-supported-in-internet-explorer-11-or-microsoft

Which essentially states that IE11 now like Chrome and FireFox no longer supports this... But since the user reports Chrome working for the website (and my Windows 10 Edge can load the website as well then...)

This seems to leave two explanations:

- The webhost is using another unsupported cipher?
- There is some security software blocking IE/WinInet at the API level on the users computer (the user states this is not the case)

Comment: Can you please inform us which exact version of IE 11 browser and exact build and update of Windows 7 OS your client is using? If there is any latest update available for Windows 7 OS then you can inform your client to install it and again check for the issue. Windows 7 OS is out of support scope of Microsoft. If possible then you can inform your client to upgrade to the latest Windows OS.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you fixed it?

Comment: Gave up. The customer (I sell a software product online) felt it was poor choice using Windows API for HTTP/HTTPS and was not particular helpsome... Still, I would obviously be interested in understanding the issue to better document/solve it.

Comment: I will start a bounty. There is something going on with some Windows 7 installs I think. It is okay if I can solve it, but I would like to document it for my users.

Comment: Could it somehow be related to what ciphers has been installed for used with TLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7 
Maybe some Windows 7 installs have installed some optional updates? While others not

Comment: I also found this which seems to have some interesting information reagrding the problem occuring on computers where admin had been changing installed ciphers: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2147528-windows-7-ie-11-tls-error

Comment: This also seems relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/7o9sd3/windows_7_tls_precedence/

Answer (score 1):

**Do you have SSL 2.0 enabled?**

SSL 2.0 and TLS 1.2 are not compatible with each other in Internet Explorer 9 and later versions.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/cannot-display-https-site